# How do I check if the user's input exists in the database table?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda, dbcontext

So I have my `Weapons` database. The way my application works is so if the user types in something in the textbox my program will search for the `WeaponName` table to see if it exists.

The problem is when I used this Lambda/LINQ, it cannot use it as a bool value.

```
private WeaponEntities dbContext = new WeaponEntities();

if (dbContext.Weapons.Where(weapon => weapon.WeaponName == searchBox.Text))
{

}
```

Comment: No but you can count if there were 0 or more....

Comment: use [`.Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.linq.enumerable.any%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check if something exists using `Any`

```
dbContext.Weapons.Any(weapon => weapon.WeaponName == searchBox.Text)
```

This expression would return `true` if any entity matches the expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can use <strike>either</strike> Any <strike>of Exists to do this.</strike>

```
dbContext.Wepons.Any(w => w.WeaponName.Equals(searchBox.Text, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
```

<strike>or</strike>

```
dbContext.Wepons.Exists(w => w.WeaponName.Equals(searchBox.Text, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
```

I suggest Exists because it tends to outperform Any.

Comment: Actually you cant use exists here since it's defined on `List`. And `Any` doesnt really have that bad performance since it will return as soon as it finds a matching element. However if performance is what you are after you probably want to go sql and use the `EXISTS` keyword.